# how to properly shuffle my data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to shuffle my data with the command in Tensorflow.

The image data is matched to the labels.

if I use the command like this:

```
shuffle_seed = 10
images = tf.random.shuffle(images, seed=shuffle_seed)
labels = tf.random.shuffle(labels, seed=shuffle_seed)
```

Will they still match each other?.

If they don't how can I shuffle my data?

Comment: If you pass the same seed to each function call, images and labels should still match each other.

Comment: @Tinu I tried a test program.```    shuffle_seed = 10
    a1 = tf.range(10)
    a1 = tf.reshape(a1, [5, 2])
    a1 = tf.random.shuffle(a1, seed=shuffle_seed)
    a2 = tf.range(0, 10, delta=2)
    a2 = tf.reshape(a2, [5, 1])
    a2 = tf.random.shuffle(a2, seed=shuffle_seed)
    print(a1)
    print(a2)``` And the outputs are: tf.Tensor(
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [8 9]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[4]
 [6]
 [8]
 [0]
 [2]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=int32)

Process finished with exit code 0
They don't seem to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Keras API you can pass `shuffle=True` to the [`fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) function, in fact its `True` by default.

Otherwise if you like to do it manually, one way is to convert your tensors to numpy array (`tensor.numpy()`), create permutated indices and use convenient numpy indexing and convert back to tensor. Here is an example:

```
np.random.seed(10)
a1 = tf.range(10)
a1 = tf.reshape(a1, [5, 2])
a2 = tf.range(0, 10, delta=2)
a2 = tf.reshape(a2, [5,1])
print(a1, a2)
a1 = a1.numpy()
a2 = a2.numpy()
shuffled_idx = np.random.permutation(5)
a1[:] = a1[shuffled_idx]
a2[:] = a2[shuffled_idx]
a1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(a1,dtype=tf.int32)
a2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(a2,dtype=tf.int32)
print(a1, a2)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [2]
 [4]
 [6]
 [8]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[4 5]
 [6 7]
 [0 1]
 [8 9]
 [2 3]], shape=(5, 2), dtype=int32) tf.Tensor(
[[4]
 [6]
 [0]
 [8]
 [2]], shape=(5, 1), dtype=int32)
```

This solution works for images of shape `(N, height, width, channels)` and labels of shape `(N,)` exactly the same.

I'm not sure if this is the fastest / most effective / best way, maybe there is one without converting to numpy arrays.

Comment: Actually I'm using different Image data generators for my data so I have to manually shuffle the data before splitting them. So thanks for your answer! It solved my problem.